# Replace a word in a textbox with another word

Tags: vb.net, text, textbox

I'm trying to create a profanity censor tool, where if a certain word was inputed, it would be replaced with "[redacted]" for example.

This is all I've got so far, any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim textbox1 As New TextBox

For Each chr As Char In Me.TextBox1.Text
'character will now be stored in chr variable
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.Replace instead of trying to do the replacement yourself. Here is an MSDN page with a link to the reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It would look something like this in your code:

```
Dim textbox1 As New TextBox
Me.textbox1.Text = Me.textbox1.Text.Replace(profaneWord, "[redacted]")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be checking the words as the user types, you could use chars or you could set up a text changed event to run when the user presses space and check the most recently typed word.

Another way could be where the user presses enter signifying he is done, use `Me.TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")` to make an array of words, and check each word. If a "naughty" word is found, replace it, and reassemble the string.